# Android layout shape without using background image?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How can i make a layout look like following snap in the case i don't want to use background image.

Answer (score 1):

Create a nine patch image of a single image. Following link is helpful to you for generate nine patch image.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ImageView like that triangle and put it in the place you need.

Have a look how you can create triangle using xml: [Android triangle (arrow) defined as an XML shape](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)

Or even you can create a TextView:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="▼"/>
```

and put it in the place.

Unicode for the triangle: [link](http://unicode-table.com/en/25BC/)

Comment: It seems a nice way to do that.is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also draw custom view:

```
public class MyBackground  extends View{
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();


    public MyBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public MyBackground(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        int triangleSide = getWidth() / 10; // triangle is 1/10-th of side
        int offsetFromRightSide = triangleSide;
        int startX = getWidth() - triangleSide - offsetFromRightSide;

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(startX, 0);
        path.lineTo(startX + triangleSide/2, triangleSide/2);
        path.lineTo(startX + triangleSide, 0);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <your.package.name.MyBackground
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Or there is one more "code way"**. Create custom background Drawable

```
public class Background extends Drawable {
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

     public Background(){
         paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        int triangleSide = getBounds().width() / 10; // triangle is 1/10-th of side
        int offsetFromRightSide = triangleSide;
        int startX = getBounds().width() - triangleSide - offsetFromRightSide;

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(startX, 0);
        path.lineTo(startX + triangleSide/2, triangleSide/2);
        path.lineTo(startX + triangleSide, 0);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override public void setAlpha(int alpha) {}
    @Override public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {}
    @Override public int getOpacity() {return 0;}
}
```

And use it like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new Background());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in Relative Layout. Hope it helps you.

```
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/triangleImage"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: This would put the triangle on the left of the TextView, **vertically centered**. Which is **not** what the OP asked.